# knockout click binding failing to call JS function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of results from an API call rendering in a list (HTML below) and have added a click binding with Knockout to a JS function that basically takes the name of the result, searches an array of google maps markers for a match, then pans to the marker on the map element and opens the previously stored infoWindow. When I open developer tools I can see that there is a listener on the element for a 'click' action that points to a Knockout function, but when I click, nothing happens. Here is the gitHub repo : https://github.com/ZackBoyd/BrewMap, if that is useful and the specific code is below. I feel like I'm overlooking something very basic, thank you in advance for any help.

HTML

```
                   <ul class="results list" data-bind="foreach: filteredBreweries">
                        <li data-bind="click: $parent.goToMarker">
                            <div class="item">
                                <a class="image loaded">
                                    <img data-bind="attr: { src: iconImage }">
                                </a>
                                <div class="wrapper">
                                    <h4 data-bind="text: name"></h4>
                                    <figure data-bind="text: address"></figure>
                                    <figure data-bind="text: yearEstablished"></figure>
                                    <figure data-bind="text: type"></figure>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

JS

```
function goToMarker(clickedBrewery){
        var clickedBreweryName = clickedBrewery.name;
        console.log(clickedBrewery);
        console.log(clickedBreweryName);
        for (var key in self.mapMarkers()) {
            if (clickedBreweryName === self.mapMarkers()[key].marker.title) {
                map.panTo(self.mapMarkers()[key].marker.position);
                infowindow.setContent(self.mapMarkers[key].marker.content);
                infowindow.open(map, self.mapMarkers()[key].marker);
            }
        }
    };
```

This code is within the scope of the 'appViewModel' function, you can see it in the repo, I didn't want to include all of it for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! It's typically expected (not to mention helpful or sometimes even a must for others to help) that you provide code *in between* the snippet you currently have, and linking to an entire repro. See "[mcve]" for guidance. (Note that you can edit your post to improve it.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the function to a variable in your viewmodel. For instance:

`self.goToMarker = function(clickedBrewery){
        var clickedBreweryName = clickedBrewery.name;
        console.log(clickedBrewery);
        console.log(clickedBreweryName);
        for (var key in self.mapMarkers()) {
            if (clickedBreweryName === self.mapMarkers()[key].marker.title) {
                map.panTo(self.mapMarkers()[key].marker.position);
                infowindow.setContent(self.mapMarkers[key].marker.content);
                infowindow.open(map, self.mapMarkers()[key].marker);
            }
        }
    };`

I don't know what your viewmodel looks like tho.
But yeah that internal function wont be exposed to the bindings i guess.